# MySQL: Add 30 days to a value in the table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to use the ADDDATE function on a value in the table.

```
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(addOns, INTERVAL 30)
```

addOns is where I store the datetime. Why can I not add 30 days?

I also tried

```
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(SELECT addOns FROM credit, INTERVAL 30)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add 30 days for date in db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609377/add-30-days-for-date-in-db)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(addOns, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
-- Or
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(addOns, 30)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you specify INTERVAL, you must specify the unit; if you don't specify INTERVAL it will default to days.

```
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(addOns, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Without interval keyword.

```
UPDATE credit SET addOns=ADDDATE(addOns, 30)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
date_add(yourDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```