# MySQL add days to a date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL. What would be the sql statement look like to add say 2 days to the current date value in the table?

```
UPDATE classes 
SET 
date = date + 1
where id = 161
```

this adds one second to the value, i don't want to update the time, i want to add two days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add 30 days for date in db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609377/add-30-days-for-date-in-db)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 30 days for date in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609377/add-30-days-for-date-in-db)

Comment: details blog: http://sforsuresh.in/date-manipulation-mysql

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Assuming your field is a `date` type (or similar):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`your_field_name`, INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
FROM `table_name`;
```

With the example you've provided it could look like this:

```
UPDATE classes 
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date` , INTERVAL 2 DAY)
WHERE `id` = 161;
```

This approach works with `datetime` , too.

Answer (score 15):

```
UPDATE table SET nameofdatefield = ADDDATE(nameofdatefield, 2) WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks for including this alternative means of adding days to a date field. I'd been looking for a way to increment a date using a stored procedure argument containing the number of days. Unfortunately, the DATE_ADD syntax doesn't allow for this.

Comment: Please always post some sort of explanation or references or something with your code.  Code-only answers do little to educate future researchers who may or may not possess a high degree of knowledge in a given language.  Giving "a little bit more" will always improve the point-earning potential of your posts and it helps StackOverflow to be not just a collection of solutions but a more comprehensive/helpful resource.

Comment: If you just want to add number of DAYS to a Date column, use the ADDDATE function. https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-adddate-function.php

Comment: `SELECT NOW() AS TodaysDate, ADDDATE(NOW(), 5) AS DateAfter5days`

Answer (score 9):

This query stands good for fetching the values between current date and its next 3 dates

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE columName BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

This will eventually add extra 3 days of buffer to the current date.

Answer (score 6):

You can leave date_add function.

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `yourdatefield` = `yourdatefield` + INTERVAL 2 DAY
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 4):

For your need:

```
UPDATE classes 
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
WHERE id = 161
```

Comment: Please always post some sort of explanation or references or something with your code.  Code-only answers do little to educate future researchers who may or may not possess a high degree of knowledge in a given language.  Giving "a little bit more" will always improve the point-earning potential of your posts and it helps StackOverflow to be not just a collection of solutions but a more comprehensive/helpful resource.

Answer (score 4):

```
update tablename set coldate=DATE_ADD(coldate, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Please always post some sort of explanation or references or something with your code.  Code-only answers do little to educate future researchers who may or may not possess a high degree of knowledge in a given language.  Giving "a little bit more" will always improve the point-earning potential of your posts and it helps StackOverflow to be not just a collection of solutions but a more comprehensive/helpful resource.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly for me as I needed to add a week to all dates in the database table.

Answer (score 3):

```
 DATE_ADD(FROM_DATE_HERE, INTERVAL INTERVAL_TIME_HERE DAY)
```

will give the Date after adjusting the INTERVAL

eg.

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) for deducting 1 DAY from current Day
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)  for adding 2 Days
```

You can use like

```
UPDATE classes WHERE date=(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) WHERE id=161
```

Comment: Upvoted for including an example of negative intervals.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Please always post some sort of explanation or references or something with your code.  Code-only answers do little to educate future researchers who may or may not possess a high degree of knowledge in a given language.  Giving "a little bit more" will always improve the point-earning potential of your posts and it helps StackOverflow to be not just a collection of solutions but a more comprehensive/helpful resource.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET date = DATE_ADD( fieldname, INTERVAL 2 DAY )
```

Comment: Please always post some sort of explanation or references or something with your code.  Code-only answers do little to educate future researchers who may or may not possess a high degree of knowledge in a given language.  Giving "a little bit more" will always improve the point-earning potential of your posts and it helps StackOverflow to be not just a collection of solutions but a more comprehensive/helpful resource.

Comment: I don't think the question: "What would be the sql statement to add say 2 days to the current date value in the table?" needs some more explanation does it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ADDDATE(d,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
from table
```