# How to add seven days to DATE field

Tags: mysql

I would like to update each DATE field and add him 7 days. i check for DATE functions in php but i didn't found function that fit to MySQL syntax
my query is:

```
$query_sched = "UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE(events.event_date + INTERVAL 7)";
$res = mysqli_query($dblink, $query_sched) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
```

Comment: UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE(events.event_date + INTERVAL 7) WHERE events.event_id = '$event_id'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL add days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Comment: try [`... SET events.event_date = DATE_ADD(events.event_date , INTERVAL 7 DAY) ...`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7820343/689579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a '+'

```
UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE(events.event_date + interval 7 day) WHERE events.event_id = '$event_id'



UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE_ADD(events.event_date , interval 7 day) WHERE events.event_id = '$event_id'
```

Output:

```
update test set test.date = date(test.date + interval 7 day) where test.id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: i got the following error on my edited code: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

Comment: I didn't have any issue : update test set date = date(date + interval 7 day) where id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: is it nessecary to add table name events.event_date ?

Comment: did you run it in php?

Comment: its should not change and even if i run the query directley at my DB i get those errors: Unrecognized keyword. (near "INTERVAL" at position 63)
Unexpected token. (near "'7'" at position 72)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 75)