# get sql results that have a timestamp date that is n number of days from today

Tags: mysql, sql

most of the results ive found while looking this up have been from getting a range of dates from today to say 30 days from now. Im just looking for the results that 14, 7, 3 and 1 day from today (each individualy)

Heres the sql i have so far

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE timestamp  (CURDATE() + 14 Day)
```

that would be the sql to get all locations that have a timestamp that is 14 days from now (this is to send out a reminder newsletter fyi).

And it shouldnt matter what time of that day it is, if possible it should grab all timestamp results from that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Location 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) IN (
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
);
```

Reference: [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Comment: it would be a seperate sql query for each, since they are completely different mailing list... so would this work? SELECT * FROM Location 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) IN (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));

Comment: Yes, it will work. Even better, you can just use "=" for that purpose instead of "IN".

Comment: thanks, quick question if you can help me out, i didnt want to have to post another question, i have another sql statement that comes right after this one that uses WHERE NOT EXISTS... and im trying to add an AND right after the not exist statement.... but its not working.   $sql="select * from ".$usertable." u where not exists (select * from ".$usermetatable." m where m.meta_key = 'course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID ) AND m.meta_value = ".$location;

Comment: I don't know how you get this query. It's little hard for me to read the actual query. I'm rephrasing your query: `select * from usertable u where not exists (select * from usermetatable m where m.meta_key = 'course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID ) AND m.meta_value = 'some location'` This should work fine. PS. I don't know the logic since I don't know what you're trying to do, but this query should run without any error.