# mysql trigger to auto complete variable dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

I am wondering if it is possible to make a mysql trigger in 5.1 to autocomplete a date field with a variable number of days once an initialization date is entered .

Something like this: [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date) but with the number of days matching the corresponding field instead of a static number.

Here is an example of what I mean:

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us2cz.jpg)

Ideally I would like a field "return date" in "Checked out" to autocomplete based on the date a booked is checked out and the type of rental it is. So, for example, in the case of ISBN 123, the return date should be July 2nd.

Comment: can you add sample set of data

Comment: I made some example tables of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a 'new' value inside a trigger must be done BEFORE an insert or the query will continue calling itself and crash.

The proper syntax for declaring a variable is also included below.

`DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Rental_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON Rental
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE v INTEGER;
        SET v := (SELECT val (in days) 
                   FROM Rental_Days 
                   WHERE Rental_Days.attribute = NEW.attribute);
UPDATE Rental SET New.return_date = FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(New.borrowed_date) + v);
END;
$$`

Answer (score 0):

within a trigger you can select the value you want and pass it to the next statement
--example ---

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TEST_INSERT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON TEST FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET v_date = (SELECT val FROM TABLE  );
UPDATE TEST SET date = date + v_date where id = 161;
END$$
```

Comment: is v_date just a placeholder here? mysql is complaining that the variable name I've made doesn't exist. . .