# How to dynamically increment dates using strtotime?

Tags: php, for-loop, increment, strtotime

I need to get 26 dates from a starting point. The next date starting from the previous one. It would be insane to hard code everything... So I was wondering how can I do this dynamically? Is there a smarter way? I'm looking to increment after the second date. Maybe with a for loop?

```
    <?php
    //incrementing dates for bi-weekly (26 periods// 26 dates)
    $firstdate = strtotime("+17 days", strtotime("2017-04-03"));//1
    $i = date("Y-m-d", $firstdate); echo date("Y-m-d", $firstdate);//echo for testing
    echo'<br>';
    $seconddate =strtotime("+14 days", strtotime($i));//2
    $ii = date("Y-m-d", $seconddate); echo date("Y-m-d", $seconddate);//echo for testing
    echo'<br>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Try and tag this with the language first, then more esoteric things after.

Comment: what is the amount you want to increment the dates by? is it a constant amount or a changing amount?

Comment: @user3299379: After the second date it would always be +14 days

Comment: sounds like you have it figured out.  what exactly are you asking?  do you want us to write the loop for you?

Comment: @billynoah: I have it half figured out... I need to get 26 variables from the loop so that I can insert them in the database... which is where I struggle. I wouldn't be here if I had it all figure out. Mind you I'm new to Php.

Comment: Seeing this is db-related; why don't you do this straight in the query during the insert/update and then add/substract in mysql also and using a `WHERE` clause if required? That's what I take from this. If we knew what this was for exactly, maybe a mysql solution would be better than php.

Comment: seems you already have a solution. just add a loop and have these two lines in the loop $seconddate =strtotime("+14 days", strtotime($i));  $i = date("Y-m-d", $seconddate); $i will have the dates you're looking for.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: while I understand what you're saying it's a bit chinese to a noob who just started few months ago. But I guess that would be a good solution if I work on finding how to do it.

Comment: @SebastianFarham This Q&A on Stack will better explain/outline what I mean http://stackoverflow.com/q/7820322/1415724 and a manual reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
// initialize an array with your first date
$dates = array(strtotime("+17 days", strtotime("2017-04-03")));

// now loop 26 times to get the next 26 dates
for ($i = 1; $i <= 26; $i++) {
    // add 14 days to previous date in the array
    $dates[] = strtotime("+14 days", $dates[$i-1]);
}

// echo the results
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be with an array

```
$myDates = [];
$firstdate = strtotime("+17 days", strtotime("2017-04-03"));
array_push($myDates, date("Y-m-d",$firstdate));
for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){
    $lastdate = $myDates[$i];
    $nextdate = strtotime("+14 days", strtotime($lastdate));
    array_push($myDates,date("Y-m-d",$nextdate));
}    

echo "<pre>".var_dump($myDates)."</pre>";
```