# How can I add days to a date in MYSQL in a query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to add 5 days to a date in MYSQL in a query. This is what I have done:

`SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN partner on user_id = idpartner WHERE DATE((end_date) + 5) >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 0,50000`

But this is not showing the list of sales which has ended. Can someone please tell me where I am making a mistake.

Comment: You use DATE_ADD( yourdate, INTERVAL 5 DAYS) instead. Please consider looking in MySQL manual before asking such trivial questions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Comment: @Gnudiff...Sorry for the trivial question but the end_date is of 'datetime' type and its not working for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want rows where `end_date` is later than five days ago.

The best way to get that is with

```
 WHERE end_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

The business of adding integers to dates doesn't work in MySQL (it's an Oracle thing). So you need to use the `INTERVAL n unit` syntax.

You'll notice that my WHERE clause above is functionally equivalent to

```
 WHERE DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 5 DAY >= DATE(NOW())
```

But, the first formulation is superior to the second for two reasons.

1. if you mention `end_date` in a WHERE clause without wrapping it in computations, your query can exploit an index on that column and can run faster.
2. `DATE(NOW())` and `CURDATE()` both refer to the first moment of today (midnight). But `CURDATE()` is a bit simpler.

Comment: I changed it to `SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN partner on user_id = idpartner WHERE DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 5 DAY >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 0,50000` and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the original query, you can use DATE_ADD with the INTERVAL keyword:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    sales
        INNER JOIN
    partner ON user_id = idpartner
WHERE
    DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY end_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 50000
```

Said that, I wouldn't recommend applying functions such as DATE_ADD on columns, as it means that the database won't be able to use an index on end_date. Therefore, I would modify the query to:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    sales
        INNER JOIN
    partner ON user_id = idpartner
WHERE
    end_date <= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY end_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 50000
```

As you can see, in the second alternative all functions are applied on constants and not on columns (`end_date`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
DATE_ADD() here is the 
[Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
Select DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM DUAL
```