# Laravel select query, 30 days from given date

Tags: laravel

I have this query i'm trying to build, where my date is 30 days more than my created_at.

Below would be what I have and need;

```
->select('orders.invoice_no as invoice_no', 'users.name as customer_name', 'orders.created_at as invoice_date', 'orders.created_at (need to plus 30 days here) as due_date)
```

Basically where my `created_at` as `due_date` is, i need to add 30 days to that particular part, so that my `due_date` is 30 days more than my `created_at`.

I would appreciate any and all help. cheers!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168521/how-can-i-add-days-to-a-date-in-mysql-in-a-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DB::raw with `INTERVAL`

```php
->select('orders.invoice_no as invoice_no', 'users.name as customer_name', 'orders.created_at as invoice_date', DB::raw('(orders.created_at + INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS due_date'))
```

or use selectRaw with `INTERVAL`

```php
->selectRaw('orders.invoice_no as invoice_no, users.name as customer_name, orders.created_at as invoice_date, (orders.created_at + INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS due_date')
```

Comment: it has to be with DB::raw right? can i use DB::table?

Comment: @UdhayanNair you can just add `DB::raw('(orders.created_at + INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS due_date')` in your select, It works with eloquent builder or query builder.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 $duedate = Orders::find(1);
 $duedate->created_at->addDays(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->select('orders.invoice_no as invoice_no', 'users.name as customer_name', 'orders.created_at as invoice_date', DATE_ADD('orders.created_at', INTERVAL 30 DAY) as due_date)
```