# UPDATE MySQL query to move data 7 days forward

Tags: php, mysql, data-manipulation

I have this website programmed with PHP and of course using MySQL as the Database Tool. I need to move my data one back back or ahead.

The first image shows the set up I have right now.
[image: Original Image]

And by clicking on the PUSH 1 WEEK link on the top right corner, the second image show what I want to accomplish. You can see that the information/data moved one week ahead.

[image: I try to accomplish this]

Third image shows my table scheme

[Table Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP7Up.png)

I would like to get help on how to word my UPDATE or what are the guidelines to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Delete everything and insert the data from your form. All in one transaction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add your database schema (the table you reference)

Comment: I just added my table as well @rollstuhlfahrer

Comment: that's what I initially thought, but my problem is, how to make it so that the date is moved by a week... @FelippeDuarte

Comment: You could use javascript to move data from one column to another.

Comment: I am trying to stay away from JavaScript, but I actually already used it a couple of times... do you have a reference of how to do this?? @FelippeDuarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be archived with a simple SQL statement ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820343/1392490)):

```
UPDATE table 
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date` , INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE `id` = 161;
```

This adds 7 days to all entries that match the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thank you...this is exactly what I needed!