# PHP SELECT to query date field plus 6 hours

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to query a date field to select all entries that are equal to or greater than current time + 6 hours. The commented first entry works, but it is the second entry that I am battling with. I know this syntax is nowhere near correct.

```
//$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND date_added >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY order_id DESC";

$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND  CURRENT_TIME >= date_added +6 hours";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Comment: It would be easier to it with php functions to calculate the resultant date and then updating the database. 
so first get the date manipulate with php time functions and then update the database

Comment: `ADDTIME(now(), '06:00:00')` or `DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)`

Comment: Many thanks the ADDTIME option worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND  NOW()>= DATE_ADD(date_added,INTERVAL 6 HOUR)";
```

This query will get your date_added value and add 6 hours to it and after will compare it with the `CURRENT_TIME`. I would suggest to use `NOW()` instead of `CURRENT_TIME` in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `DATE_ADD` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)) function. In your case:

`` $query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND your_date_field >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIME, INTERVAL 6 HOURS)"; ``

would likely do what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND  CURRENT_TIME >= DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)";
```