# Add days in dateadd but needed format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" using sql query

Tags: sql, dateadd, getdate

Current date - 04/06/2021 12:11:25 AM

Value I want to set is plus 29 days but using sql query.

I tried

```
update TableName set value = DateAdd(d, 29, getdate()) where SomeCondition
```

But its changing format of date to `Jul 3 2021 12:30PM`. I need `03/07/2021 12:30:21 AM`

Comment: Relational databases are for the storage and retrieval of relational data. I don't see how the above fits with that concept.

Comment: Your sql statement does not appear to be mysql; please tag with the correct database system.

Comment: follow this, you have syntax error https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820343/12709358

Comment: Which dbms are you using? getdate and dateadd are product specific functions.

Comment: Don't confuse data with *representations* of that same data. If you're correctly storing your dates in a datetime column, it *won't have a format at all*. You need to concern yourself with format when you're *presenting* the data to users. If you're storing dates as strings in the database, that's the main problem here.

Answer (score 0):

NOW() is your friend.

try:

```
update TableName set value = date(now()  + interval 29 day) where SomeCondition;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this for MySQL:

```
UPDATE TableName SET VALUE = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 29 DAY) WHERE SomeCondition;
```

However, you seem to be confusing MySQL functions with SQL Server ones, so I will also give you the syntax in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE TableName SET VALUE = DATEADD(DAY, 29, GETDATE()) WHERE SomeCondition;
```