# MySQL add 365 days in previous saved value of datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to add 365 days in previous saved datetime column.

Here is my code:

```
$update_count = "UPDATE shops SET   
date_expiry = DATE_ADD('',INTERVAL 365 DAY)
WHERE shop_url = '$shop_url' ";
```

But this code did not work. I want to add 365 days in previous saved value in `date_expiry` table.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the column name when calling the `DATE_ADD()` function:

```
$update_count = "UPDATE shops SET   
date_expiry = DATE_ADD(date_expiry,INTERVAL 365 DAY)
WHERE shop_url = '$shop_url' ";
```